# Problem creating PHP app with MySQL connection using docker-compose

Tags: php, mysql, docker, mysqli, docker-compose

I have a problem using Docker.

I want to create a PHP container that connects to mySQL container with persistence using a volume.

I create the mySQL using this:

`docker run -d --name database -e MYSQL_DATABASE=bd -e MYSQL_USER=web -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=web -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass_root mysql:5.7`

I create the image of PHP using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

COPY index.php /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

EXPOSE 80
```

In the same directory I have Dockerfile and index.php.

The code of index.php:

```
<?php
  echo "<h2>con PHP</h2>"
?>
<?php
$servername = "database";
$username = "web";
$password = "web";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Then I run this to create the image:
 `docker build -t prueba .`

I run the container webapp linking to the container database:
`docker container run -d -p 80:80 --link database --name webapp prueba`

Now I test the connection in the browser at localhost:

> Mi WebApp
> con PHP
> Connected successfully

**THE PROBLEM (Docker-compose):**

1. I delete the webapp and database containers
2. I try to repeat the same process but using Docker-compose (docker-compose version 1.25.5, build 8a1c60f6).
3. docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    container_name: database
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'bd'
      MYSQL_USER: 'web'
      MYSQL_PASS: 'web'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'pass_root' 
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - mydb:/var/lib/mysql
  web-app:
    image: prueba
    container_name: webapp
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
volumes:
    mydb:
```

4. I run docker-compose up -d
5. Both containers are created.
6. Now I test the connection in the browser at localhost:

**Mi WebApp**
con PHP

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/html/index.php on line 11
Connection failed: Connection refused
```

7. 

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' webapp

Out: 172.18.0.3
```

8. Now I test the connection in the browser at 172.18.0.3:

**Mi WebApp**
con PHP

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'web'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/index.php on line 11
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'web'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)
```

9. I don´t know how to make this work. Any help would be appreciated.

**TL;DR**
MySQL connection works creating containers using commands, but it doesn't work with docker-compose.

Comment: Did you tried providing the database name to your connection ? (4th parameter to the MySQLi constructor)

Comment: @AymDev Thanks for your reply. I just tried adding the db to index.php and update the mysqli connection but I am in the same situation. If I create both containers without using docker-compose it works fine, but not with docker-compose.

Comment: Okay. I may be wrong but I think Docker Compose allows your containers to comunicate by using their **service id** and not the container names. I don't know why it worked before as you used `--link` which I never used (you should stop using it too). In short: try using `db` instead of `database` in `$servername`.

Comment: Okay, I have tried what you said but that's not the solution. Same error message.

Comment: Well the difference is that the error message is the same in localhost and the container ip.

Comment: Okay, I don't see what's causing the issue. If you don't find the root cause, maybe you'll want to try my [Docker PHP playground](https://github.com/AymDev/docker-php-playground) repository.

Comment: @AymDev Thanks for your code. I used it as my template to build my PHP app.